# Is there a pseudo class like nth-of-type that also considers children of same type?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Look at the following example:

```css
.card{
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

/* Important below */

.card:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color: red;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color: green;
}
.card:nth-of-type(3){
  background-color: blue;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4){
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">A</div>
<div>
  <div class="card">B</div>
  <div class="card">C</div>
</div>
<div class="card">D</div>
```

I am want each of the `.card` divs to have another `background-color`. However, `:nth-of-type` only considers siblings:

> The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position among siblings of the same type (tag name). [-mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

But in my case, I also want to consider the order of all `.card` elements, also the ones that are **inside a parent and not a direct sibling** of the others.

The desired result should look like this:

```css
.card{
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.card:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color: red;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color: green;
}
.card:nth-of-type(3){
  background-color: blue;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4){
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">A</div>
<div class="card">B</div>
<div class="card">C</div>
<div class="card">D</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript and knowing that by spec the order of `document.querySelectorAll(".card")` is guaranteed to be top down DFS (the order you want) you can do so using javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(function(elem, index) {
  elem.classList.add("card-" + (index + 1));
})
```

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.card-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.card-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.card-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.card-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">A</div>
<div>
  <div class="card">B</div>
  <div class="card">C</div>
</div>
<div class="card">D</div>
```

Comment: Instead of making a counter variable, use the index of the forEach loop: `.forEach(function(elem, index) { elem.classList.add("card-" + index); });`.